# Passing handle object to C++ leads to reference leak?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I've come across this issue while debugging a simple for-loop where the iteration time would grow overtime. The issue seems to stem from the fact that passing a handle object to a C++ MEX function extends the lifetime of the handle until the end of the script.

Here is a minimum example to reproduce the issue.

First, the class simply let us track when the object gets deleted:

```
classdef Foo < handle
methods
  function this = Foo()
  end
  function delete(this)
    disp("DELETE FOO");
  end
end
end
```

Then, the C++-MEX function does nothing:

```cpp
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function
{
public:
  void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList /*outputs*/, matlab::mex::ArgumentList /*inputs*/) override
  {
  }
};
```

Compile this (work_with_Foo.cpp) with:

```
>> mex work_with_Foo.cpp
```

Finally, the testing script:

```m
index = 0;
while index ~= 3
  v = Foo();
  clear v;
  index = index + 1;
end
disp("End of regular loop");
index = 0;
while index ~= 3
  v = Foo();
  work_with_Foo(v); % pass the handle to the C++ MEX function
  clear v;
  index = index + 1;
end
disp("End of work_with_Foo loop");
```

Which provides the output:

```
DELETE FOO
DELETE FOO
DELETE FOO
End of regular loop
End of work_with_Foo loop
DELETE FOO
DELETE FOO
DELETE FOO
```

Actually, if you insert more work after the second loop you can see that the handles are not deleted before the script ends.

Is this a known issue and is there any way to work around it?

The same behavior has been confirmed on Matlab R2018a on Linux and Matlab R2019a, R2018b on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried to call v.delete before clearing the handle in the workspace? Try this:
delete(v) followed by clear v

Comment: Yes. In fact this calls the destructor of `Foo` properly but if you bump up the number of loop iterations significantly (e.g. from 3 to 1000000) you can see two things:
1. a noticable delay at the end of the script after the last `disp` call (suggesting some cleanup is happening) which doesn't happen if you do the same with the loop that doesn't pass the object to the mex function
2. If you tic/toc the loop body it takes more and more time

(edit: sent by accident before typing point 2)

Comment: I guess the delay is due to the time you need to destroy the object. And about bumping the loop iterations and tic/to c... well, as you surely know, matlab is no c++... It's an interpreted language. I you need v to be deleted, I'd say you need to call delete.

Comment: The delay happens if I explicitly delete the object in the loop. The point is to show that MATLAB is keeping track of a lot of temporary objects that it shouldn't have to and it seems to be triggered by passing it to a C++ mex function